# ¿Como mantener tab al refrescar la pagina?

Tags: javascript, html, css

No soy experto,pero me llama la atención la forma en que funcionan esos componentes web,hablo de los **tabs**.

Buscando ayuda-ejemplos(código),he encontrado este codepen:

https://codepen.io/nat-davydova/pen/PMJJRM?editors=0010

Me gustaría implementarlo en mi página web de prueba,pero al recargar la página este me lleva al primer tab.

Veo que en sitios donde lo usan,en la barra de direcciones, al cambiar de tabs,la dirección va cambiando.Por ejemplo:

```
www.stackoverflow/tab1
www.stackoverflow/tab2
www.stackoverflow/tab3
```

Y si recargo la pagina en cualquier tab,ese contenido permanece ahi.
¿Alguna ayuda al respecto?

Comment: No, a menos que lo guardes como preferencias. Como por ejemplo, podría ser en `localStorage`.

Comment: Cuando se trabaja con pestañas, generalmente se usan `hashes` para identificar la que está activa, por ejemplo `stackoverflow.com/#tab1` y necesitas un poco de Javascript para leer el hash y mostrar la pestaña que corresponda, Probablemente te sirva [escuchar cambios de hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

Comment: @Triby, está interesante. Lo estoy probando ahora mismo. Creo que es mejor que usar `localStorage`.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM., hace algunos meses hice un script de pestañas para probar algunos experimentos que he desarrollado y me funcionó perfecto tomando el dato de la URL, de ahí mi sugerencia. No suelo usar `localStorage`, pero OP ya tiene dos opciones para investigar y tratar de lograr su objetivo.

Comment: @Triby Amigo, encontré un ejemplo de lo que quiero. Pero tengo una inquietud: ¿Por qué cuando actualizo la pagina estando en un tab diferente al primero, en ese tab por unos segundos se puede ver el contenido del primer tab? Esto sucede cuando estoy usando Edge,pero no sucede en Firefox

Comment: @luis, eso es relativamente normal, porque se tiene que cargar el DOM para poder aplicar los cambios necesarios. Ante la duda, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar tu código y ver si podemos encontrar alguna opción para evitarlo.